# Set Model to a specific object from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set the model of a DOM element to a specific child object given a specific attribute.  in this specific example, the "Employees" object is structured in this fashion:

```
var Employees = [
    {EmployeeID:1000
     Name: Jimmy
     ManagerID: null}
    {EmployeeID:1001
     Name: James
     ManagerID: 1000}
    {EmployeeID:1002
     Name: Steve
     ManagerID: 1000}

]
```

I was hoping that an inline Curley Brace Directive using a filter would be able to help me out with it.  What follows obviously doesn't work, but hopefully it demonstrates what I would like it to do.

```
<div ng-repeat="Emp in Employees">
        <span>Employee #:{{Emp.EmployeeID}}</span>
        <img src="../../Content/images/Photos/{{Emp.EmployeeID}}.jpg"/>
        <h4>{{Emp.Name}}</h4>
        <h5>Manager:</h5>
        <!--The following is what I do not know how to do-->
        <span>{{Employees.Name | filter:Employees.EmployeeID = Emp.EmployeeID }}</span>
</div>
```

With the End Result being:

```
Employee #:1000
<img>
Jimmy
Manager:
<!--I'll figure out what to do with null values in a bit.  first things first-->

Employee #:1001
<img>
James
Manager:
Jimmy

Employee #:1002
<img>
Steve
Manager:
Jimmy
```

Comment: You can use a function that you define on your scope to have it resolve the manager name from the EmployeeID and bind to it with curly braces.  The other option is to make an interceptor that processes the data as it's returned (or just deal with it in your service or wherever you retrieve the data, or better yet on the server side).

Comment: if I go the function route, and if I have that function return the entire employee object for the manager, could it work like `{{getManager({{Emp.EmployeeID}}).Name}}` ?

Comment: I believe what you wrote will work as well, except you would leave out the extra internal set of curly braces, angular will properly interpret Emp.EmployeeID within the ng-repeat (honestly I haven't entirely wrapped my head around how it parses all the things I throw at it, but so far I haven't hit a limit on the wonky things that it can understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.employees = [
        {EmployeeID:1000,
         Name: 'Jimmy',
         ManagerID: null},
        {EmployeeID:1001,
         Name: 'James',
         ManagerID: 1000},
        {EmployeeID:1002,
         Name: 'Steve',
         ManagerID: 1000}
    ]

    $scope.findManager = function(empId) {
      console.log('here');
        //debugger;
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.employees.length; i++)
        {
            var curEmployee = $scope.employees[i];
            console.log(curEmployee.EmployeeID)
            if(curEmployee.EmployeeID == empId)
                return curEmployee.Name;
        }
        return "";
    }
});
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="Emp in employees">
        <span>Employee #:{{Emp.EmployeeID}}</span>
        <img ng-src="../../Content/images/Photos/{{Emp.EmployeeID}}.jpg"/>
        <h4>{{Emp.Name}}</h4>
        <h5>Manager:</h5>
        <!--The following is what I do not know how to do-->
        <span>{{findManager(Emp.ManagerID)}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EhJLu/